# Motivation for the definition of the Artin Conductor of a representation

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations, local-field

I'm trying to figure out what the Artin Conductor of a representation is using Chapter IV.$2\text-3$ of Serre's Local Fields, and I'm struggling to understand the motivation behind its definition.

---

If $L/K$ is a finite Galois extension of local fields with integer rings $\mathcal O_L=\mathcal O_K[x]$, $G = \mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ and $f = [\overline L:\overline K]$ is the residue degree, then we define $i_G(s) = v_K(s(x)-x)$ for $s\in G$ and
$$a_G(s) =\begin{cases}-f\cdot i_G(s) & \text{if }s \ne 1\\\\f\displaystyle\sum_{s\ne 1}i_G(s)&\text{if }s=1\end{cases}$$

We then define for any class function $\varphi$
$$f(\varphi) = (\varphi,a_G)$$
so that
$$a_G = \sum_{\chi}f(\chi)\chi$$
as a sum of irreducible characters. We then deduce some key properties about $f$ - in particular that we have

$$f(\chi)=(\chi,a_G)=\sum_i\frac1{(G_0:G_i)}\dim(V/V^{G_i})$$
where $G_i$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ ramification group of $G$ and $\chi$ is the character of a representation $\rho:G\to \mathrm{GL}(V)$. We can then define the *local conductor* of $\chi$ to be the ideal $\mathfrak f(\chi)=\mathfrak p_K^{f(\chi)}$ which we can extend to the *global conductor* by taking a product over primes.

---

My question is:

> What motivates this definition?

Once we have defined $a_G$, the definition of $f$ seems natural; I'm unclear as to why we would define $a_G$ in the first place, and why we would then use it to construct an ideal $\mathfrak f(\chi)$.

Comment: I think you're putting the cart before the horse a little. I prefer to think of $f(\chi)$, the Artin conductor of a representation, as the key object here; and the point of its definition is quite clear: to measure how nontrivial the action of higher ramification groups is on $V$. Then one observes that an additive function on characters $\chi$ must be given by $\chi \mapsto \langle a, \chi \rangle$ for some $a$, and $a_G$ is just what one cooks up in order to do this.

Answer (score 1):

One important motivation is the [conductor-discriminant formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductor-discriminant_formula), which says
that for $L/K$ a finite Galois extension of number fields, we have
that the discriminant of $L$ over $K$ is equal to the product
$\mathfrak f(\chi)^{\chi(1)},$ where $\chi$ runs over all irred.
characters of the Galois group of $L/K$.

Maybe more relevant to you is the local version of this formula,
which takes exactly the same form, except that now $L/K$ should be a finite Galois extension of non-archimedean local fields.

Comment: Thanks! I guess my key question is what motivates the initial definition of $a_G$ so that formulae like this naturally occur?